# CORS policy error for Salesforce Community

Tags: community, customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder

I am trying to configure Heap analytics JS script in our Salesforce Community and getting a CORS policy error from the Community origin URL. I am adding the Heap script in the Head markup of the Community page.

I tried adding the URL to the Salesforce CORS Allowed Origin by going to Quick Find -> Security -> CORS but still getting this error.

[image]

Wanted to know how I can get around this error? or is it not possible as per this idea: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DiyFAAS

Answer (score 1):

Found that the issue was not from the Salesforce end and was from the Heap endpoint we were calling. Heap needed to add the Salesforce community domain to their CORS list